# paper-dropdown-menu font size

Tags: polymer, font-size, dropdown

I'm trying to change the font size of what is selected in a `paper-dropdown-menu`, but everything I've tried is failing. I've tried:

```
--paper-input-container-label: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-input-container-input: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-input-container: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-dropdown-menu: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-dropdown-menu-input: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-item: {font-size: 8px;};
--paper-item-selected: {font-size: 8px;};
```

Everytime, the rule was put in the `:root` selector
but none of these work...

here's my code:

```
  <paper-dropdown-menu no-label-float class="rowsSelector">
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="{{limit}}" attr-for-selected="value">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{options}}">
        <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: `:root` works if you are using HTML file. If you are styling it in custom element then it is `:host`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in a 'style is="custom-style"' tag and target the tag with a class or id unless you only have one dropdown menu or want them all to have the same font, font size etc..

Add below style code to adjust the font to be 20px. Notice the class to target the element I want to style, the class in my example is "test". If you do not want to use a class simply target all paper-dropdown-menu elements by changing .test with paper-dropdown-menu.

If you want to separate your custom style into its own file I believe that it has to be a HTML file for it to work.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    .test {

        --paper-input-container-label: {
          font-size: 20px;

        };
    }
</style>
<paper-dropdown-menu class="test" label="Dinosaurs">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```